# Как добавить пробел посередине числа?

Tags: javascript

Вот мой пример реализации данной задачи, но он не работает.
На выходе у меня получается `123456`, а должно получиться `123 456`.

```js
if (this.money.toString().length == 6) {
    this.money.toString().charAt(4) + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const num = 123456;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(num))
```

Answer (score 5):

А как же старый добрый [`Number.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) ?

```js
console.log((123456).toLocaleString('ru-RU'))
```

Comment: @Дмытрык да, но этот метод так же принимает локаль и  я изменил ответ =)

Comment: ну все, теперь не придерешься) ... + самый первый поставил)

Comment: @Дмытрык а я Вам сейчас как поставлю